# AngularJs - Communication between directive and service

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that handles file upload and download .. by calling service functions. 
The problem is that I have a progress bar for uploading files and I want it to be synchronized with the file that I am uploading, and to achieve that, I have to get the e.loaded value of the progress event (see code sample below) each time this value changes.

Here is the upload function of my service :

```
function upload(file, attachableId, className, appName){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", file);
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                data: fd,
                url: URL+"?attachableId="+attachableId+"&className="+className+"&appName="+appName,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                uploadEventHandlers: {
                    progress : function(e){

                      // I want to access the value of e.loaded in my directive each time it changes 
                      // so that I can update my progress bar

                      console.log(e.loaded + " uploaded of " + e.total);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

I don't know how to get that value in the directive from the service knowing that I call the service upload function only one time in the ng-click of the upload button.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You could get `progress` function as a parameter so that every directive/component can pass its own progress function and it’ll be called every time progress updates.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I am not sure how I'll do it, can you please explain more ?